# VueJS reactivity: Replace an array with data

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuex

I still have trouble why certain ways of changing data work, while others do not. I tried this example:

```
    watch: {
      '$store.state.linedata': function() {this.redraw()}
    },
    methods: {
      redraw() {
        this.chartOptions.series[0].data = this.$store.state.linedata
      }
    },
    data() {
      return {
        chartOptions: {
          chart: {
            type: this.type
          },
          series: [{
            data: this.$store.state.linedata,
            name: "Test Series",
            color: this.color
          }]
        }
      }
  }
```

This setup works, whenever I change the `linedata` in my store, the component gets updated. However, for me it would be more intuitive to update the data like this, without referencing `this.chartOptions.series[0].data`:

```
  redraw() {
    this.$store.state.linedata = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
  }
```

This will update the state correctly, but however not cause to update the component with the new data. Why does the second way not work and is my first way the correct way to do it? I feel like I am missunderstanding some core concept here.What would a best practice look like?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Vuex docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html) you can read:

> The only way to actually change state in a Vuex store is by committing a mutation

It means that you should not try to do `this.$store.state.linedata = [1,2,3,4,5,6]`. It may throw an error depending on your Vuex settings in the console by the way. Instead, create a mutation like so:

```js
mutations: {
  updateLineDate(state, lineDate) {
    state.lineData = lineData;
  }
}
```

And then call:

```js
this.$store.commit("updateLineDate", [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]);
```

To automatically update your chart's data, I would suggest creating a computed property in your Vue component. To make it reactive to changes, map your attribute using `mapState`:

```js
import { mapState } from "vuex";

// ...

computed: {
  ...mapState("lineData"),
  chartData() {
    return {
      chart: {
        type: this.type
      },
      series: [{
        data: this.lineData,
        name: "Test Series",
        color: this.color
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

Then remember to provide `chartData` to your chart component instead of `chartOptions` in my example.

Comment: thank you for the great explanation, I will have a look at all that stuff :-)

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: I changed code but it still does not update, only the data gets updated. Also changed the Chartoptions to chartdata of course :-(

Comment: Which chart library do you use? Highcharts wrapper for Vue? If so, did you set the `updateArgs` property like to `<highcharts :options="chartData" :update-args="[true, true, { duration: 1000 }]" />`

Comment: don´t know if that solved the problem, but now it works :-)